# Can CartoDB and Mapbox.js talk?

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, carto

Back in December it seemed there was no way to bring in a CartoDB layer into a Mapbox.js or Tilemill project.

Has this changed?

(http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/mapbox-tiles/763-cartodb-and-mapboxjs-how-do-they-talk)

I'd like to implement this on a few local government projects I'll be working on shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another example that may be useful:

```
...
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.uncompressed.js"></script>
<script src='http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.2.0/mapbox.standalone.js'></script>
...
function main() {
  var map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoomControl: false,
    center: [43, 0],
    zoom: 3
  });

  L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-20v6611k').addTo(map)
  cartodb.createLayer(map, 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json').addTo(map)
}
```

full example here: https://gist.github.com/javisantana/7200781